# Evaluation Search and Replace in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a file formatted like this:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
9558    9629    gene
            locus_tag   CeraR_t011
            gene    trnR-UCU

11296   9773    CDS
            locus_tag   CeraR_p012


            gene    atpA
            product ATP synthase CF1 alpha subunit

            transl_except   (pos:complement(10268..10270), aa:Q)
            transl_except   (pos:complement(11192..11194), aa:Q)
            transl_except   (pos:complement(13267..13269), aa:M)
11296   9773    gene
            locus_tag   CeraR_p012
            gene    atpA
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I need to add 809 to both of the values following pos:complement in each instance.  I have been attempting with the search and replace modifier as so:

```
$line =~ s!complement((\d+)..(\d+)!complement(($1+809)..($2+809)!eg
```

however, the ( after complement is always interpreted as part of an evaluation rather than simply a character.  I have tried every combination of backslashes, apostrophes, and quotes to make it just a character but nothing seems to work.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since the replacement string is evaluated, you must use a quoted string and concatenations:

```
$line =~ s/complement\(\K(\d+)..(\d+)/($1+809) . '..' . ($2+809)/eg;
```

Note: since `\K` removes all on the left from the match result, you don't need to rewrite all the begining of the match in the replacement string.